Structure required for differentiability in topological context
I am a bit unsure about precisely what structure is required for a function to be differentiable, or even continuous for that matter. Specifically, what structure are we using in the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition behind the scenes? This confusion came to me specifically in the context of topology, so I'll expand my issue a bit further.
Consider we have some topological manifold $M$, with some charts $(U,\phi)$, $(V, \psi)$. By definition, the coordinates are homeomorphisms, and so the transition map $\phi \circ \psi^{-1}$ is also a homeomorphism, and so it is continuous (as a map between topological spaces).
$\phi \circ \psi^{-1}$ is a map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, and there is a claim that this coincides with the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity (I haven't seen a proof of this so let me know if this is incorrect). The $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity uses some metric to measure how far away points are from each other.
On the other hand, homeomorphisms only require topological structure, where we have no metric a priori. So I don't understand how we can discuss continuity without adding some additional structure to $\mathbb{R}^n$ (with the standard topology). Is it the case that there is some extra implicit structure, or some natural induced metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (using e.g. that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is metrisable)? Or is my understanding wrong somewhere?
Essentially, I don't know what structure is required for $\epsilon-\delta$ calculus, and what assumptions are being made when we define differentiable structures on topological manifolds.

Note that whilst I have focused on continuity, my question is about differentiability more generally, which I imagine in the $\epsilon-\delta$ context needs exactly the same structure as continuity. I am aware that there is a notion of continuity (but as far as I know not general differentiability) for sequences, but I am specifically interested in relating things to $\epsilon-\delta$ continuity.

In order to talk about differentiability you need the full structure of $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. its vector space structure together with the Euclidean norm. Because these are essential in defining derivative.
If you are only interested in continuity then topology alone is enough. The $\epsilon-\delta$ continuity is equivalent to topological continuity. In particular, it doesn't depend on metric/norm, only on the underlying topology.

Thank you, that makes sense. If I could clarify two things: firstly, you could equip $\mathbb{R}^n$ with any Banach structure right? And secondly, am I correctly understanding that no extra structure is required on the original topological manifold, just on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Although isn't it also the case that all norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent, so the Euclidean norm is as valid a choice as any?

@Bedge the definition of derivative requires a norm. While all norms are equivalent this doesn't directly translate to derivatives. I think that the definition and value of derivative does not depend on the norm. But this is a different question. Either way some choice is needed, typically the Euclidean one.

Your observation about Banach structure is correct. In finite dimensional case, for a fixed dimension the choice doesn't matter. But it does open doors to infinite dimensional calculus.

The original topological manifold does not have more structure. Depending on the class of manifold we consider, we will only require the transition maps to be of some differentiability class. E.g. $k$ times differentiable or smooth, or analytic, etc.
